# Using SQL DELETE query with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I’ve written a program in VB.NET in conjunction with a SQL server database table to record the assessment marks of students. The SQL table (Marks) details columns, which show Student_ID, Assessment (e.g. Maths, Science, English) and Mark.
 
The subroutine shown below is designed to allow users to delete specific assessments and, by using the DELETE statement nested within a conditional if/elseif clause, I have managed to achieve this, the program runs fine. However, as a relative newcomer to programming I am conscious about adopting good practice and, if possible, avoiding repetitive code which, in my mind, is clearly evident within the if/elseif clause. This problem becomes increasingly relevant when considering the possibility of having to deal with 15 or more student assessments.
 
My question is, can the SQL query statement be modified to incorporate an ‘assessment’ variable rather than explicitly typing in each condition within an if/elseif clause? I tried to do this in the same way as the variable ‘id’ is used to identify the ‘Student_ID’ within the SQL query statement, but this returned an error stating that, for example, Maths is not a column. 
 
Hope I have explained this sufficiently and everything makes sense.
Any ideas, as always, most appreciated.

Thanks, Mike

```
   Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.Write("Enter assessment to be deleted : ")
    Dim assessment_name As String = Console.ReadLine

    If assessment_name = "Maths" Then
        query = ("DELETE FROM Marks WHERE Assessment='Maths' AND Student_ID=" & id)
    ElseIf assessment_name = "English" Then
        query = ("DELETE FROM Marks WHERE Assessment='English' AND Student_ID=" & id)
    ElseIf assessment_name = "Science" Then
        query = ("DELETE FROM Marks WHERE Assessment='Science' AND Student_ID=" & id)
    ElseIf assessment_name = "Art" Then
        query = ("DELETE FROM Marks WHERE Assessment='Art' AND Student_ID=" & id)
    End If

    command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Side note; look into using parameters rather than String concatenation. Also look into implementing `Using`

Comment: Wither parameters, the `WHERE` clause can be refactored to `WHERE Assessment=@Assessment AND Student_ID=@Id;`. That would allow you to use a single query in addition to the other benefits of parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Had a little problem figuring out how to declare the parameters for assessment and id, but I got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like below.

You can use parameters to easily create your query.

You can use a `USING` block for easy dispose

```vb
Public Sub DeleteNote(ByVal Assessement As String, ByVal Studentid As Integer)
    'Using statement for easy dispose
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString), _
          command As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Marks WHERE Assessment=@Assessement AND Student_ID=@Studentid", connection)

        'Add parameters
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assessement", Assessement)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Studentid", Studentid)

        'Open the connection
        connection.Open()
        'Execute query
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                'Read result of query
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                     reader(0), reader(1)))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: clearing the connection pool like that is very poor practice. It breaks the connection re-use feature built into the pool. Typically, it's better to let exceptions bubble up to a higher level of abstraction. Return codes add complexity that don't help the application... they tend to be ignored, and hide details about the error. I also cleaned up a few other things.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you missed the `'` around the `Assessment='@Assessement'` :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I think it depends on the program on mine due to extensive sql integrety testing i cant read the bytes of the file etc as long the connection in opened as the pool keeps the file open.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks I didnt notice since not using IDE haha actually I had them but someone edited them out

Comment: @Mederic you can see who edited them out by clicking on the link to see the [revision of the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43708991/revisions) ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.... got everything up and running using the parametric approach as advised. Thanks to people like you...I'm learning something new everyday. Cheers!

Comment: @Mike No problem glad to help if you have any more questions don't hesitate and don't forget mark the question as answered if it was.